# How to use stored procedures in NHibernate for Create/Update when working with database view

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a SQL Server view **CyclesList** on the table **Cycle**. **Cycle** table contains a few columns, and **CyclesList** view add some more data that can be computed on database level.

And now, I have a NHibernate mapping that points to **CyclesList**:

```
<class name="Cycle" table="CyclesList">
```

However, I would still like to work with **Cycle** class, and perform Create/Update operations , but I have to use stored procedure that will access **Cycle** table directly. Is there a way to achieve it in NHibernate? I would appriciate a sample mapping/links to resources with samples. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find some information in the docs under ["Native-Sql -> Custom SQL for create, update and delete"](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-cud). Basically, you need the "sql-insert", "sql-delete" and "sql-update" elements in the mapping file.

There is also [an example on Ayendes blog](http://ayende.com/blog/1692/using-nhibernate-with-stored-procedures).